# flash audio player for m4a (AAC) audio file embedded in html

Tags: html, flash, aac, m4a

I'm looking for a (free) flash player that I can embed in my site and use to play a .m4a (.mp4 with AAC audio) file that will be obtained using a URL (i.e. it's not local to the server hosting the web page).

I've tried searching on google for one, but either I'm searching wrong or no one has made such a thing.  Ideally this would be very simple (small user interface with play button and maybe a progress bar) and it would be easy to have multiple instances of on an html page (can create the player with an `<object>` tag).

1. Does such a player exist?
2. I'm pretty sure flash supports .m4a (AAC), but am I wrong?

Comment: I have a media player that would work with the MPEG-4 files that FLVPlayback supports, unfortunately I can't send you a copy as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW Player supports AAC/m4a http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

> ...file that will be obtained using a URL
>   (i.e. it's not local to the server
>   hosting the web page).

You may run into cross domain issues, Flash Player won't let you play media from another domain unless that server has policy files that allow it (like a http://www.other-site.com/crossdomain.xml).

Comment: yes, I eventually put the right combination of search terms into google to find this one.  Appears that it will meet my needs.  Our solution will probably require a license at some point, which is unfortunate, but acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

FLVPlayback can be used to make a video player. It's not overly difficult.

> Note: Protected MP4 files—such as
>   those downloaded from Apple® iTunes®
>   or digitally encrypted by
>   FairPlay®—are not supported.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fe9.html

Comment: I'm not looking for a media player, only a bare-bones audio player that will play .mp4.  I also am looking for a .swf (and any accompanying .js file necessary) that I can just drop into my application.  Developing in ActionScript is not an option at this time.

Comment: You might have to roll your own media player. It's really not that difficult if you have flash. I don't have any sources to a good open-source one.